# LPF Second Order use cascade

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

[image]

What is the minimum value of $R_2$ (in $R_1$) to minimize loading effect?

Please explain the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Passive Low Pass Filter](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html) "*to reduce the loading effect, 10x from the previous stage implement the impedance such that R2 = 10 x R1 and C2 = 1/10th C1*".

Conceptually the target 2nd-Order Filter Corner Frequency and 2nd-Order Low Pass Filter -3dB Frequency will dictate the R and C component values.

In practice the ideal R and C valued don't exist in the open market, and engineers make compromises to design the best circuit. The calculation may require a resistor value of 11.6 Kohm and capacitor value of 157 micro farads. These components don't physically exists in the market. Therefore designers are required to make compromises.

Below are some equations and graphs to complete this discussion.

2nd-Order Filter Corner Frequency

[image]

2nd-Order Low Pass Filter -3dB Frequency

[image]

n is the order number, which 2 for this discussion.

Frequency Response of a 2nd-order Low Pass Filter

[image: *enter image description here*]

Comment: what is the loading effect and so where does R2 = 10R1 actually come from? thanks

Comment: The multiplication factor of 10 in equation $R_2$ = 10$R_1$ is an engineering design decision. Other design decisions such as $f_c$ and component availability might change the multiplication factor.